# Some strange graph from "RelationshipGraph"

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want use this code to graph the all of function in image-processing.

```
 g = Through[
      EntityList[
        EntityClass[
         "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", 
          "ImageFunctions"}]][
       EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "RelationshipGraph"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I wanna union these graph like

```
CommunityGraphPlot[GraphUnion @@ g]
```

But I get some error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I want get it `Head` to see

```
First@g // Head
```

> Out[30]= Style

What about I get on earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your list `g`, each graph is wrapped in the following `Style` directive:

```
Style[..., ImageSizeMultiplies -> {1}]
```

where `...` is the actual `Graph` object you're looking for (you can see this with something like `FullForm @ First @ g`). This tells Mathematica to render the individual graphs at full size even when displayed in the list you get. That's indeed a bit inconvenient for working with the graphs directly, but we can see that this `Style` is completely irrelevant to the actual graph, so it's trivial to pull out the graph and discard the `Style`:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[GraphUnion @@ First /@ g]
```

[image]

Comment: `Style` fool me....